# Archive failed - no reason - Xcode 6 with Screen shot of archictures

Tags: xcode, archive, xcode6.3

Im trying to archive my iOS application but it fails during archiving, there is no hint to what it may be. Any way to find out?

Ive provided an image of the build settings incase the issue lies here:

[image]

[image]

**Update** 
App builds perfectly on a device. (iPhone 5s and 6)

Comment: "it fails during archiving" How do you know? What actually happens?

Comment: @matt because it pops up on the screen 'failed' this occurs when its nearly completed compiling all source files.

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 6.3.1. Okay, I have no evidence that this will make any difference. But it does "fix bugs", so you never know...

Comment: Build active architecture only should be NO for Release mode

Comment: @Thedude unfortunately it didnt fix it

Comment: @matt ill try this, is there any other information I could provide to you? Im inheriting an old project and Im unsure what might be causing the issue. Failing during archiving is new to me

Comment: @Thedude code signing added above

Comment: @matt code signing added above

Comment: The fact that your build settings were wonky is suspect. I would suggest making a whole new clean project from the template and moving all the code / resources into it. It doesn't take very long, and you are certain of having good default values everywhere.

Comment: @matt its quite a big project :(  I removed arm64 and it archived, but now wont build due to an architecture issue with cocoappods

Comment: Well, that's excellent. It sounds like you now know where to look.

Comment: Now if you can just remember what the heck you did, you can answer your own question! :))))

Comment: @matt so I was able to submit to the app store, please see the answer, you might find it interesting :)

Comment: Very much so. Thanks for posting that answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. I originally thought it was an issue with the architecture, so I removed arm64 from valid architectures. This then allowed me to archive the app.

However I decided to do one last build on a device before submitting it to the app store and I noticed it would not build (would not build on an iPhone 5s running iOS8.3).

This flagged an error when trying to build, I had:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
SEC_IS_BEING_DEBUGGED_RETURN_NIL();
#endif
```

in my code, which i felt was needed in order to deter debugging by an unauthorised individual. I removed this line, added back 'arm64' into 'Valid architectures' and it archived without any issue (it also ran on the device again). So for some reason, 'arm64' allowed the above code when running on a device I believe, but would not archive.

Hope this saves someone too :)